# How to default to side-by-side view in GitLab

Tags: diff, gitlab, git-diff

How can I make Side-by-side be the default diff for my GitLab installation or project or profile?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Update February 2016

The issue is now at [issue CE 3071](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3071) and... was resolved by [commit 9fdd605](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/9fdd605fd2e4550170e5ef088bec7c6d2585c4a5)!
A cookie now retain your diff view choice, with GitLab 8.5.0+.

---

Original answer (February 2015)

That doesn't seem to be possible right now, and can be voted up at the  [suggestion 7082397](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/7082397-remember-side-by-side-diff-choice)

> #### Remember side-by-side diff choice
>
> Right now when I want to review code, I have to choose side-by-side diff each time I open a Merge Request because that choice is not stored/saved anywhere.
>
> Either store my last choice/change of viewer globally somewhere and use it on all diff views from that point on.
> Or let me have a config option on my account where I can specify my preferred choice.

The side-by-side diff view was introduced with [GitLab 6.4](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/8c7d342a284a53da80c9028f73eb8fa3ed83af28) (Dec. 2013) with [commit b51c2c8](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/b51c2c81189c291c2af0fcd07a409731dbcb91ed).

Answer (score 6):

Change the setting once from the gear icon at the top-right of any diff, and it should hold across other diff sessions.

[image]