# How to default to side-by-side view for diff in GitWeb?

Tags: git, git-diff, gitweb

I find this post [How to default to side-by-side view in **GitLab**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180650/how-to-default-to-side-by-side-view-in-gitlab), the answer was "not possible".

What about **gitweb**? Can I default to side-by-side view in GitWeb?

Comment: The only option to default to side by side is to modify the CGI script. You would need to change the default from `inline` to `sidebyside` in the `git_commitdiff` subroutine. https://github.com/git/git/blob/e05806da9ec4aff8adfed142ab2a2b3b02e33c8c/gitweb/gitweb.perl#L7792

Answer (score 1):

Note: default diff view choice is now (since February 2016, GitLab 8.5.0) possible, and retained by a cookie (I have updated my old answer)

I don't see a similar option in gitweb (see [gitweb.perl#L7768-L7787](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e05806da9ec4aff8adfed142ab2a2b3b02e33c8c/gitweb/gitweb.perl#L7768-L7787))

You can try and use the `?diff_style=sidebyside` url parameter though.